# Is it OK to copy the content of a .js file on the HTML page to save HTTP request?

Tags: javascript

We have a shopify store which uses too many .js files that we want to save the HTTP requests of. It's just [one file](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js) that's just a single liner:

```
(function(undefined) {}).call('object' === typeof window && window || 'object' === typeof self && self || 'object' === typeof global && global || {});
```

Which is referred to from our web page as this:

```
<script src="//cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is it safe to remove this HTTP request and then just use on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(undefined) {}).call('object' === typeof window && window || 'object' === typeof self && self || 'object' === typeof global && global || {});</script>
```

Both ways are equivalent and it won't be any problem this way right?

Comment: Haven't tested but I don't see why not. It should work exactly the same because you are basically just doing the same thing by using the referring script tag. (At least, the javascript will execute in the same scope)

Comment: It is possible but you should still include a comment or reference that the script you are including is the script you are using to avoid copyright issues.

Comment: Though it works, as long you are aware with XSS prevention it should be no problem. If you're implementing [CSP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html#refactoring-inline-code) you need to add a hash value in the CSP header.